# Is there a term for this "gripper" UI element?

Tags: icon, symbols, interface-design

What is the official name of this image [image: gripper]? It is often found on the side of a panel widget for dragging.

Is it named "gripper"? A Google search doesn't return a lot of results for "gripper icon".

Comment: We can help you identify the name of this sort of UI element, but resource gathering is too broad for our community. Also, A screenshot of where this element is used would be helpful.

Comment: Should be migrated to UX.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Very few UI elements have names that approach anything close to being 'official'. There's plenty of common terms for a lot of the common UI elements, but even then, one shop may call it one thing, while another a something different.

So, use what you want and your team agrees upon. "gripper" is as good as any.

Comment: The two most common terms are "handle" followed by "gadget." Gadget has dropped out of fashion over time, since it has been co-opted as a term for mostly useless programs.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery library calls this icon '**ui-icon-grip-dotted-horizontal.**'

Reference: http://api.jqueryui.com/theming/icons/